# Knife Vcloud plugin 404 Error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I downloaded vcloud plugin from the URL https://github.com/astratto/knife-vcloud and I setup the configuration using:

```
knife vc configure command
```

and entered the details below:

```
URL - 'https://1.1.1.1/abc/cloud/org/abc-lab/'
username - 'karthik'
Password - abc
```

Where 'abc-lab' is the organization name in the vcloud environment. Once the configuration file is created, I gave the following command:

```
knife vc org list
```

And it returned 404 resource not found error.

Comment: I don't think that is the correct URL - I think you just want `https://1.1.1.1` and then specify `--org-login ORGANIZATION`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also tried the URL https://1.1.1.1 but still get the same error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What about https://1.1.1.1/abc/cloud?

Comment: It did not work either. Thanks for the reply.